# Cannot execute Windows Form .exe on Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu

Tags: .net, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I've installed the .NET SDK on my Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu to run my Windows Form applications. If i try to run it the following error shows up:

`bash: ./programname.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

As far as I know thats because the application wasn't created with a ARM64 system.

Is there any way getting around that error?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.exe` is a Windows executable, and won't run on Linux. Likewise, Windows Forms is dependent on Windows-specific APIs and again won't run on Linux.

Technically there might be a way with Wine or Mono but that's another topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

Did I understand it correcrly, that it should work if I install Windows on the Raspberry?

Comment: @wiag-est That's correct. Though Windows ARM64 is not officially out yet (i.e. Insider Previews only), so there will be bugs and performance issues. But in theory, it would be runnable. (The app also needs to be compiled ARM64.)

Comment: How could I compile it to ARM64?

Comment: @wiag-est [Instructions here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5311216/Building-a-Native-Windows-on-Arm-App-with-WinForms), however, the app will still only run on Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found a way to run windows on my RPi